# PowerShell + BMC Remedy + Web Services

Tags: web-services, soap, powershell, remedy

I'm having considerable difficulty inserting authentication information when using any of the Remedy web services.

```
$URL = "https://itsm.url.com/arsys/WSDL/public/server_name/HPD_IncidentInterface_WS";
$URI = New-Object System.Uri($URL);
$ITSM = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $URI -Namespace ITSM;
$Credentials = New-Object ITSM.AuthenticationInfo;
$Credentials.userName = "UserName";
$Credentials.password = "PassworD";
$Credentials.authentication = '';
$ITSM.AuthenticationInfoValue = $Credentials;
```

The code dies on the last line shown.
This is the error message generated:

```
Exception setting "AuthenticationInfoValue": "Cannot convert the "ITSM.AuthenticationInfo" value
of type "ITSM.AuthenticationInfo" to type "ITSM.AuthenticationInfo"."
At C:\\ITSM Automation\Automate Incident Modification.ps1:45 char:8
+     $ITSM. <<<< AuthenticationInfoValue = $Credentials;
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

"Cannot convert the "ITSM.AuthenticationInfo" value of type "ITSM.AuthenticationInfo" to type "ITSM.AuthenticationInfo"."  ...um...  What?  How does one troubleshoot this?

If anyone has ideas, I'm all ears.

The function 'New-WebServiceProxy' can be found [here](http://poshcode.org/1340).

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug reported on the `WebServiceProxy` when re-using the same `Namespace` value in a session. If you are hitting this, you can either close and re-open powershell, or avoid using the `-Namespace` parameter.

See the bug report on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/711529/an-error-is-thrown-executing-multiple-times-in-the-cli-a-script-that-uses-namespace-parameter-in-the-new-webserviceproxy-cmdlet).

Comment: Any update whether this was fixed or is there any workaround available? The linked site redirects to page not found.